# Datetime not matching format

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string into a datetime. However is says that I don't follow the format and I am confused. Could anyone help me please?

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('2021-11-27 00:00', '%y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

**Error:**

> ValueError: time data '2021-11-27 00:00' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M'

Comment: voting to close because of typo - use `%Y`. Or even better: check out [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) first. Btw. you can also use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) here, which doesn't even require a parsing directive (since it expects ISO format)

Answer (score 2):

The `%y` code matches a two-digit year - for a four-digit year, you should use `%Y` instead.

```
date = datetime.strptime('2021-11-27 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), `%y` is

> Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

and `%Y` is

> Year with century as a decimal number.

so

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('2021-11-27 00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
date
```

will give
`datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 27, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python too much but [this documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) `%y` is for year **without** century but `%Y` is for year **with** century:

| Directive | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| %y | Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number. |
| %Y | Year with century as a decimal number. |

So, looks like the correct format should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`

Here a [`demonstration`](https://ideone.com/wxMCIz).

Remember, almost all programming languages have this custom specifiers and most of them are case sensitive.